# Hibernate one to many not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, one-to-many

I have two question regarding one to many mapping.

Code:

User.java

```
public class User {

private String firstName;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "userID", sequenceName = "userID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "userID")
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

private String lastName;

@Column(name = "reset", nullable = false)
private Integer passwordReset;

@Column(name = "useremail", nullable = false, unique = true)
@Email
@NotEmpty
private String email;
@Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
private String password;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", optional = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private Role role;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private List<CreditCards> creditCards;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id")
private List<WashingOrder> orderList;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "{username}")
private String username;

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public List<CreditCards> getCreditCards() {
    return creditCards;
}

public void setCreditCards(List<CreditCards> creditCards) {
    this.creditCards = creditCards;
}

public Integer getPasswordReset() {
    return passwordReset;
}

public void setPasswordReset(Integer passwordReset) {
    this.passwordReset = passwordReset;
}

public List<WashingOrder> getOrderList() {
    return orderList;
}

public void setOrderList(List<WashingOrder> orderList) {
    this.orderList = orderList;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName="
            + lastName + ", username=" + username + ", password="
            + password + ", role=" + role + "]";
}
```

}

WashingOrder.java

```
    public class WashingOrder {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "orderNo", sequenceName = "orderNo")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "orderNo")
@Column(name = "orderNo")
private Long orderNo;

@Column(name = "totalClothes", nullable = false)
@NotNull
private Integer totalClothes;

@Column(name = "mensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer mensCloth;

@Column(name = "womensCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer womensCloth;

@Column(name = "otherCloth", nullable = true)
private Integer otherClothes;

@Column(name = "deliveryDate", nullable = true)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-mm-dd")
private Date deliveryDate;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = true)
private String orderStatus;

public Long getOrderNo() {
    return orderNo;
}

public void setOrderNo(Long orderNo) {
    this.orderNo = orderNo;
}

public Integer getTotalClothes() {
    return totalClothes;
}

public void setTotalClothes(Integer totalClothes) {
    this.totalClothes = totalClothes;
}

public Integer getMensCloth() {
    return mensCloth;
}

public void setMensCloth(Integer mensCloth) {
    this.mensCloth = mensCloth;
}

public Integer getWomensCloth() {
    return womensCloth;
}

public void setWomensCloth(Integer womensCloth) {
    this.womensCloth = womensCloth;
}

public Integer getOtherClothes() {
    return otherClothes;
}

public void setOtherClothes(Integer otherClothes) {
    this.otherClothes = otherClothes;
}

public Date getDeliveryDate() {
    return deliveryDate;
}

public void setDeliveryDate(Date deliveryDate) {
    this.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
}

public String getOrderStatus() {
    return orderStatus;
}

public void setOrderStatus(String orderStatus) {
    this.orderStatus = orderStatus;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "WashingOrder [orderNo=" + orderNo + ", totalClothes="
            + totalClothes + ", mensCloth=" + mensCloth + ", womensCloth="
            + womensCloth + ", Others=" + otherClothes + ", deliveryDate="
            + deliveryDate + ", orderStatus=" + orderStatus + "]";
}
```

}

Here user is trying to palce a order calling the below method.

```
   public Long placeOrder(WashingOrder order) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    long id = 1;
    Query query = session.createQuery("from user where id =" + id);
    User emp6 = (User) session.load(User.class, new Long(1));
    User user = (User) query.uniqueResult();
    List<WashingOrder> washingOrder = new ArrayList<WashingOrder>();
    washingOrder.add(order);
    System.out.println("washingOrder" + washingOrder);
    emp6.setOrderList(washingOrder);
    session.persist(order);
    session.persist(user);

    Long orderID = (long) 1;
    return orderID;
 }
```

Question:

1. Right now I have hard code the user id as 1.How to pass this dynamically once the user is get logged in.
   Whether I have keep the username or id in session and pass it in every method to get the user details.
2. When I try to add the order to the particular user, the existing user value ID get removed from the existing data and updated to the new one. Please see the hibernate query output when I try to add the order to the user.

Output:

```
  Hibernate: insert into ClothDetails (deliveryDate, mensCloth, status, otherCloth, totalClothes, womensCloth) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
  Hibernate: select creditcard0_.id as id6_2_0_, creditcard0_.creditID as creditID1_3_0_, creditcard0_.creditID as creditID1_3_1_, creditcard0_.creditcard_number as creditca2_3_1_, creditcard0_.expiry_month as expiry_m3_3_1_, creditcard0_.expiry_year as expiry_y4_3_1_, creditcard0_.payment_type as payment_5_3_1_ from usercreditcards creditcard0_ where creditcard0_.id=?
  Hibernate: update ClothDetails set id=null where id=?
  Hibernate: update ClothDetails set id=? where orderNo=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to store user id in session and use it wherever you need the value. If the user id is changed, then you need to update the value stored in the session. Basically, you need a user id in the session and you need to make sure it is fresh.

Comment: what about the second one?

Comment: My answer stated that the id must be fresh. If it is deprecated, then naturally you cannot use it. Howeber, I wonder whether you really wanted to modify the user id.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a Principal class in the servlet specification for managing logged in users. If you are not on a servlet environment (you do not tell), then you should keep a reference to the User object. This gives you access to both the User and the users id. Do not relay on disconnected numbers.
2. You have a mismatch in your relation mapping. The @JoinColumn(name = "id") in User.java points to "id". Is this your foreign key? Are you sure that is not "orderNo"?

You should also make sure you have a relation between WashingOrder and User as well, as there is no explicit reference mapped as it stands now.

Comment: I am new to spring mvc. Can you please explain the mapping where I went wrong

Comment: orderNo is the primary key of washingOrder table and the id is the name of the foreign key on the washingOrder table side.

Comment: Washing order has no mapping to the User.
Try adding this to WashingOrder.
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;